# How can I conditionally join two MySQL tables on multiple fields?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

In my MySQL DB, I have 2 tables: `pos_tables` and `pos_user_login`. In
`pos_tables`, I have four staff fields: `staff1`, `staff2`, `staff3`,
`staff4`. These 4 fields hold the IDs of staffmembers stored in
`pos_user_login`. In `pos_tables`, these staff IDs may repeat, but `staff_id`
is the primary key in `pos_user_login`.

What I'm trying to do is to join these two tables, using a condition of

```
if pos_user_login.staff_id=(pos_tables.staff1 OR
                            pos_tables.staff2 OR
                            pos_tables.staff3 OR
                            pos_tables.staff4)
```

... and if any of the 4 fields from `pos_tables` matches the primary key from
`pos_user_login`, then fetch that record from `pos_tables`.

What query do I need to run to do this?

---- EDIT ----

Should I use something like this?

```
SELECT *
    FROM pos_user_login pu
    WHERE pos_user_login_id IN (SELECT *
            FROM pos_tables
            WHERE staff1 = pu.pos_user_login_id
            OR staff2 = pu.pos_user_login_id
                                           ...);
```

---- EDIT 2 ----

SAMPLE RECORD

```
pos_tables
----------
table_number (1   )
staff1    (10)
staff2    (11)
staff3    (12)

pos_user_login
--------------
staff_id (10),
type (drinks_person)
staff_id(11), type (order_taker)
staff_id(12), type(cleaner)
```

After comparing using the WHERE condition `(type="drinks_person")`, the output
should be:

```
table_number(1), staff1(10), staff2("null"), staff3(null)
```

Comment: Provide sample data, and expected output.  Because using a JOIN will produce duplicates if 2+ child records relate to a given parent.  And `SELECT *` will return columns from all tables involved in JOINs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There it´s

```
select  a.*
from    pos_tables a left join
        pos_user_login b1 on a.staff1=b1.staff_id left join
        pos_user_login b2 on a.staff2=b2.staff_id left join
        pos_user_login b3 on a.staff3=b3.staff_id left join
        pos_user_login b4 on a.staff4=b4.staff_id
where  (b1.staff_id is not null or 
        b2.staff_id is not null or
        b3.staff_id is not null or
        b4.staff_id is not null)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `IN()` operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM pos_tables JOIN pos_user_login 
  ON pos_user_login.staff_id IN (
    pos_tables.staff1,
    pos_tables.staff2,
    pos_tables.staff3,
    pos_tables.staff4
  )
```

Comment: It's true you could use the In operator and this is a smart thing to do, however, if you actually want to join the tables, then this alone will not suffice

Comment: @Jason: Actually i want to get records with atleast one of the 4 fields in pos_tables matching pos_user_login. For that is it better to use this answer ?

Comment: oh okay, yes, then this answer would make more sense. Checking for existence of the record, this would work well.

Comment: @Jason: Explain, because both inner and outer joins require criteria, which this answer provides. Criteria doesn't mean data exists to support it, and without criteria effectively is a cross join/cartesian product.

Comment: @The Scrum Meister: You realize that matching on 2+ staff members will produce duplicate rows?

Answer (score 1):

Sort of sounds like the data hasn't been stored very well. Can you post a schema?

Here's my suggestion: using ifnull and doing multiple joins you can work out if one of the id's has a join. I've returned "name" assuming that the pos_user_login has that field, but you would return any field you need.

```
SELECT 
     ifnull(p1.id,
        ifnull(p2.id,
           ifnull(p3.id,
              ifnull(p4.id,
                  'no matching record',
              p4.name,
           p3.name,
        p2.name,
     p1.name) as staff_name
FROM
     pos_tables t
      LEFT JOIN pos_user_login p1 on staff1=t.id
      LEFT JOIN pos_user_login p2 on staff2=t.id
      LEFT JOIN pos_user_login p3 on staff3=t.id
      LEFT JOIN pos_user_login p4 on staff4=t.id
```

Comment: why do i have to ifnull here ? i just need to check one field against 4 fields on another table ? cant we do it as "The Scrum Meister's" answer ??

Comment: @Deepak upon further understanding of your question I agree with @TheScrum

Comment: now tel me why did we use ifnull ? how does the output affects if we use ifnull and IN ?

Comment: ifnull will allow you to check if there is a suitable join, and because i'm using a bunch of left joins, it will actually make the join. In Scrum's response, the join is made based on the "in" clause being true. In that sense it is a superior response.

Comment: This will only show **one** of the staff member names in the event that more than one exists.  The value will fall in sequence with the staff column (1,2,3,4,5, etc).  IE: if 2 and 5 matched, you'd only see the name for #2.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: Actually there is no way for that kind of matching. Actually the final filter applied to the result is either 2 or 5 so there will be just one record returned from the query.